# JQuery onClick - Have Panel slide out right from under the map when an area is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've tried every variation of slide/slidetoggle/ but I can't seem to get the details panel to appear when Kings Cross is clicked on the map

MAP HTML

```
<img src="https://imgur.com/p4z9t0T.png" id="Zone1TubeMap" alt="Zone 1 
Tube Map" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area id="KX" alt="Kings Cross St Pancras" title="" href="#" 
shape="rect" coords="474,58,488,111"/>
<area alt="Baker Street" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="221,94,252,124" />
<area alt="South Kensington" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="131,359,146,384" />
<area alt="Oxford Circus" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="287,208,303,225" />
<area alt="Embankment" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="383,370,410,398" />
<area alt="London Bridge" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="594,385,608,402" />
<area alt="Liverpool Street" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="682,156,700,192" />
<area alt="Old Street" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="593,104,613,124" />
<area alt="Leicester Square" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="380,268,398,283" />
<area alt="Paddington" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
coords="47,91,89,145" />
</map>
```

PANEL HTML

```
<div class="boxes">
<h1> Kings Cross St Pancras | Coffee Shop </h1>
<small> Details about the Coffee shop </small>
<img src="https://ats-alltopstartups.netdna-ssl.com//wp-
content/uploads/2016/12/How-to-Open-a-Coffee-Shop-.png" width="340px" 
height="195px"> </div>
</div>
```

PANEL CSS

```
.boxes {
background-color: white;
border: solid red 5px;
margin-bottom: 18px;
color: rgb(0,5,142);
opacity: 1; 
}
```

Comment: Made a testing Area - https://jsfiddle.net/mghe4kcb/

Comment: Demo works fine once you include jQuery and fix typo https://jsfiddle.net/nj3h65Ld/

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from the question what kind of slide do you want, but the following code works fine. you can change the styling of the .box div as you wish

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Narrabundah College Fashion Show </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .boxes {
        background-color: white;
        border: solid red 5px;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
        color: rgb(0,5,142);
        opacity: 1;
        display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#KX").click(function(){
                $('.boxes').slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Media Video -->
   <img src="https://imgur.com/p4z9t0T.png" id="Zone1TubeMap" alt="Zone 1 
    Tube Map" usemap="#Map" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area id="KX" alt="Kings Cross St Pancras" title="" href="#" 
        shape="rect" coords="474,58,488,111"/>
        <area alt="Baker Street" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="221,94,252,124" />
        <area alt="South Kensington" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="131,359,146,384" />
        <area alt="Oxford Circus" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="287,208,303,225" />
        <area alt="Embankment" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="383,370,410,398" />
        <area alt="London Bridge" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="594,385,608,402" />
        <area alt="Liverpool Street" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="682,156,700,192" />
        <area alt="Old Street" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="593,104,613,124" />
        <area alt="Leicester Square" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="380,268,398,283" />
        <area alt="Paddington" title="" href="#" shape="rect" 
        coords="47,91,89,145" />
    </map>

     <div class="boxes">
        <h1> Kings Cross St Pancras | Coffee Shop </h1>
        <small> Details about the Coffee shop </small>
        <img src="https://ats-alltopstartups.netdna-ssl.com//wp-
        content/uploads/2016/12/How-to-Open-a-Coffee-Shop-.png" width="340px" 
        height="195px">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think something else in my code is block it, as when I add that into my head/external javacript file on my webpage it says 'Map.html:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Map.html:12'

Comment: Please make sure to include the jquery files in the the HTML.